# How can I create a plot similar to this in Java jFreeCharts?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to create a "relationship" plot something similar to this the picture below. I would like to be able to:

1. Specify size of nodes.
2. Colour bonds.

I currently use jFreeChart and would love to do it with that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that JFreeChart is the solution you are looking for.  Take a look at [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) if you want to use a java library or [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/About.php) and its java port [Grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/).

Of these, based on my experience, JUNG is the solution you need.